# Add parameter to MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

I've got an MVC application with basic view:

myapp.com/category

and a switcher to second one:

myapp.com/category/list

App is used as independent one and as also in other application into iframe where src is: myapp.com/category. I want do not show page header when it is used into iframe, how can I achieve it? I was trying to add querystring, myapp.com/category?show=false, and set this as iframe src, but when I switch to the second view the parameter is not passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper method to construct URLs that would keep the *show* parameter in place.  For example:

```
public static string GetModifiedUrl(this UrlHelper helper, string url)
{
    string qstring = helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["show"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qstring)) url += "?show=" + qstring;
    return url;
}
```

Then in the views, for example:

```
<a href='@Url.GetModifiedUrl(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))'>Home</a>
```

---

Another option is to create add a value to the session on the first request, and use that instead.  Ie, put some logic in the controller like this:

```
var qs = Request.QueryString["show"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qs)) 
{
    Session["show"] = qs;
}
```

Then in the views, use `@Session["show"]` instead of `@Request.QueryString["show"]` to decide whether you show the header.

Answer (score 1):

Break the main view into two partial views.

Then, when calling for the master/external app, call the partial view that has just the content.

When calling the regular native app, call a VIEW that contains both the partial views (header as well as content).